# Given two linear transformations, prove that V is equal to the direct sum of the kernels.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum, linear-transformations

Let $S:V\to V$ and $T:V\to V$ be two linear transformations such that:

$T^{2} = S^{2} = 0, T\circ S + S \circ T = Id$.

Prove that $V= Ker(S)\oplus Ker(T)$.

What can I use to prove this? Honestly, I don't know where to start.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake typing it. The original says $T\circ S + S \circ T = Id$. Edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply $T$ (and $S$, respectively) to your equality you get
$$
TST=T,\ \ STS=S.
$$
If you now pre-multiply by $S$ and $T$ respectively, you get
$$
STST=ST,\ \ TSTS=TS.
$$
So $P=ST$, $Q=TS$ are projections ( $P^2=P$, $Q^2=Q$), and 
$$
P+Q=ST+TS=I.
$$
Now any $v\in V$ can be written as 
$$
v=Pv+(I-P)v,
$$
where $Pv\in\ker S$, $(I-P)v=Qv\in\ker T$.